# cut string in a file that has a "\"

Tags: string, shell, cut

I`m cutting a string in a file. The file is something like this:

```
AAAAA ;BBBBB;CCCCC ; DDDDD    ;EEEEE  ; FFFFF
```

I`m cutting each variable with:

```
   while read LINHA
   do
      CODIGO_AUX=`echo "$LINHA" | cut -f 1 -d ";"`
      if [ "$CODIGO_AUX" = "$CODIGO" ] ; then
         NOME_SERVIDOR=`echo "$LINHA" |cut -f 2 -d";"`
         HOST_FTP=`echo "$LINHA" |cut -f 3 -d";"`
         USER_FTP=`echo "$LINHA" |cut -f 4 -d";"`
         PWD_FTP=`echo "$LINHA" |cut -f 5 -d";"`
         DIR_DESTINO=`echo "$LINHA" |cut -f 6 -d";"`
         USUARIO_BANCO=`echo "$LINHA" |cut -f 7 -d";"`
         BANCO_DADOS=`echo "$LINHA" |cut -f 8 -d";"`
      fi
   done
```

But I`m having trouble because some of the possible variables that I receive are something like:
    AA\TD234
When I do an

```
echo NOME_SERVIDOR
```

they give me>>>>>  AATD234   <<<< Without the "\"
and when I try to log to the server with the FTP connection, it give my wrong login or wrong password.
Is there a way to cut the string and get it the way it is?(with the )

Answer (score 1):

You need the `-r` option for `read`.

Also, you can use the `IFS` variable to split the string into variables once instead of calling cut 8 times:

```
while IFS=';' read -r a b c d e f
do
    printf "%s='%s'\n" a "$a" b "$b" c "$c" d "$d" e "$e" f "$f"
done <<END
AAAAA ;BBBBB;CCCCC ; DDDDD    ;EEEEE  ; FFFFF
AA\TD234;BBBBB;CCCCC;DDDDD;EEEEE;FFFFF
END
```

outputs

```
a='AAAAA '
b='BBBBB'
c='CCCCC '
d=' DDDDD    '
e='EEEEE  '
f=' FFFFF'
a='AA\TD234'            <<<<
b='BBBBB'
c='CCCCC'
d='DDDDD'
e='EEEEE'
f='FFFFF'
```

Comment: When I do this the variables don`t get any value...

   while  IFS=';' read -r CODIGO_AUX NOME_SERVIDOR HOST_FTP USER_FTP PWD_FTP DIR_DESTINO USUARIO_BANCO BANCO_DADOS
   do
 printf"-----------------"
   done < ${ARQ_LOG_CFG}
Echo $VARIABLES...

Comment: I saw somewhere that the IFS=';' is before the while... is there some diference?

Comment: The IFS definition goes before the `read` command. Make sure you quote the variables when you use them: `echo "$VARIABLES"`

Comment: the $Variables are still coming empty... /=

Comment: You're reading in a while loop, but echo-ing the variables *after* the loop. Is the last line of your file a blank line?

Comment: The file is generated... by a SQLPLUS command... Yes, the last line is an blank line....

Comment: I`m using in a while loop so I can get the specific line that have the code that I want... That is why there is the if case in the example I put up there...

Comment: once you get the one you want, you need to `break` out of the while loop